# Capturing HTML to a string in PHP

Tags: php

Okay, so maybr I'm going about doing this entirely wrong, I probably am. But I would like to be able to take the HTML between a ... like so:

```
$str = ?>
... some HTML goes here ...
<?php ;
```

Am I completely off my rocker to think I can do this? I couldn't think of a way to put it into words so I could search it on Google, which is why I'm here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
ob_start();
?>
... some HTML goes here ...
<?php
echo 'php outputs are captured too';
$str = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Alternatively, if it's just a little bit of HTML (and no php code within), just write it down with one of the [string formats](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) like heredoc or nowdoc:

```
$str = <<<'NOWDOC'
... some HTML goes here
NOWDOC;
```

Comment: Works beautifully! I'm working with a MVC framework (symfony) and trying to keep to the rules and this makes things easier, for sure. AND Komodo will format the HTML this way! Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Look into [heredocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and [nowdocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc). A heredoc looks like:

```
$str = <<<HTML
  <div>This is some text!</div>
HTML;

// We're back in PHP.
echo $str;
```

If you specifically want to work with HTML, look into [XHP](https://github.com/facebook/xhp/wiki).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I haven't ever heard of XHP, it seems really interesting and useful. I think I'll install and play around with it. ^_^ It's awesome what Facebook is opening up to the OSS community. I've used Cassandra and Tornado, myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to phihag's answer.

It is possible to capture HTML with a function as well, including with anonymous functions:

```
<?php $bob = function() { ?>
... some HTML here...
<?php }; ?>
```

and later output $bob:

```
<?php $bob(); ?>
```

or capture the output of $bob somewhere else with output buffering:

```
ob_start();
$bob();
$str = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a multiline, specially delimited string for such situations.

[This talks about it a little.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried heredoc, but it didn't like the PHP sitting in it for some reason. It recognized it correctly because it threw the exception set in the class's __get() when a method isn't found.